# How fosuserbundle performs the login action without provided salt

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, symfony-2.8

In symfony 2.8 we use bcrypt as password encoding algorithm. The thing is that the salt is a random value generated each time we authenticate. So, even if I am using the same password a different salt will be used to encode it each time. And there is my question: given that the encoded password is always different, how does it match with the stored one in database??? Or maybe I am missing something. This is a basic example I performed and never  the passwords match.

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserEvents;
use FOS\UserBundle\Event\GetResponseUserEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
  use Primicia\SeguridadBundle\Entity\Usuario as Usuario;

class ServicesController extends Controller
{
    public function loginServiceAction($user,$pass,Request $request){
        $response = new Response();
        $userManager = $this->container->get('fos_user.user_manager');
        $userFos = $userManager->findUserBy(array('username' => $user));
        if($userFos== null)
        {
           $response->setContent(json_encode(array('isUser' => false)));
           return $response;
        }
        $encoder = $this->container->get('security.password_encoder');
        $encoded = $encoder->encodePassword($userFos,$pass);
        echo 'salt'.$userFos->getPlainPassword().'</br>';
        echo ('enc  '.$encoded);
        echo '</br> user'.$userFos->getPassword();

 }
}
```

if we check $encoder->encodePassword() method we find this:

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function encodePassword(UserInterface $user, $plainPassword)
{
    $encoder = $this->encoderFactory->getEncoder($user);

    return $encoder->encodePassword($plainPassword, $user->getSalt());
}
```

Here we see that we encoding using the salt of the user provided, but since we are Symfony 2.8 with bcrypt algorythm THERE IS NOT SALT IN DATABASE. So, how happens the magic here????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described in [Using the BCrypt Password Encoder](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html#using-the-bcrypt-password-encoder)

> A salt for each new password is generated automatically and need not be persisted. Since an encoded password contains the salt used to encode it, persisting the encoded password alone is enough.

In fact the `getSalt()` method needed by the implementation of the `UserInterface` in your `User` entity can returns `null` if you are using BCrypt to encode your passwords.

**Update based on the OP comment:**

You can compare the plain password with the stored one using the service:

`$encoderService = $this->container->get('security.password_encoder')`

and then it's method `isPasswordValid`

`$match = $encoderService->isPasswordValid($userFosObject, $plainPasswordString)`

that will returns true if the comparison match or false otherwise.

Comment: but then, I am trying to make a webservice which compares a given password in plain text with a system stored password. Even when passwords are the same, the encoded versions are different. That is what i was trying to achieve in the code above.How can I make it? Need to be simple, without extra vendors.

Comment: @denny I've extended my answer to include your comment (although your real need was not so clear reading your question) :-)

Comment: @denny Reading again your post and your comment (I was not really sure about what you want to achieve), I think your doubts starts when you try to compare the plain password encoding it again (and not with the stored one) and this is wrong because each time you encode a plain password, the system use a different random salt (using BCrypt). The comparison must be performed only using the method described in the answer.

Comment: like a charm. Tnks